# Codeigniter Database results - Objects or Arrays?

Tags: php, database, arrays, codeigniter, object

I've been using Codeigniter for a good while now and i've often wondered which/whether to use Codeigniter's

`$query->result()` or `$query->result_array()`

Personally, I've tended to stick with Arrays as I find it easier to manipulate the array and push items and so forth. The only thing that annoys me slightly is the simply or writing the statements in the view e.g.

`$row->title` is a lot cleaner and easier to read than `$row['title']`

but

`$row->{0}` over `$row[0]` on the other hand isn't!

I'm still in limbo as to what route to go down, if anyone can tell me more benefits of using Objects over Arrays I'd be delighted!

Comment: If you like OOPS than object have the edge

Comment: It's entirely up to you - if you prefer working with arrays, stick with them, if you prefer OOP, objects will look nicer.

Comment: Just pick one.  Whichever you want to use is fine.  Also, why would you ever use `$row->{0}`?  `$query->result()` returns an *array of objects*.

Comment: If you ever has a database column named a number e.g. 0 | 1 | 2 (for whatever reason - I've used some strange API's which have done!) then you need to reference using the bracket example above

Answer (score 2):

I prefer objects, but there is a benefit to using arrays that can reduce clutter in situations that call for performing some check or operation on all (or some) columns:

```
foreach ($row as $column => $value) { 
  if ($value == null) {
    // oh no!  null!
  }
}

// check these columns and make sure they're non-negative
$non_negative = array('amount_paid', 'income');

foreach ($non_negative as $column) {
  if ($row[$column] < 0) {
    // less than zero?  what a bum.
  }
}
```